# instance programming not read machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I created a program to turn machines on and off
but it only works to turn it off, to turn it on in the morning it doesn't work
error in a vm in the zone of São Paulo, region southamerica-east1
I have another schedule in the São Paulo zone, us-central1 and this schedule is working normally
this problem started happening about 20 days ago

I've looked in the vm logs but I can't find anything

Comment: You're going to need to provide far more details than this. What manager/software are you using (VSphere? etc) what does your script look like. Do you get any warnings or errors? etc